# Facebook friends count using python

Tags: python, facebook, api

I am trying to just know how many friends a user has. This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
>>> import facebook
>>> graph = facebook.GraphAPI("CAAEr.....XCODEe6bMZD")
>>> profile = graph.get_object('puja41')
>>> friends = graph.get_connections("puja41", "friends")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    friends = graph.get_connections("puja41", "friends")
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/visolank/Desktop/Python/programs\facebook.py", line 112, in get_connections
    return self.request(id + "/" + connection_name, args)
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/visolank/Desktop/Python/programs\facebook.py", line 298, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(response)
GraphAPIError: Unsupported operation
```

When i tried JonasR's suggestion, I got:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported operation",
      "type": "FacebookApiException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your application has not requested (or not had the user grant) access to that user's friends connection.  I can view that user's basic details in the [GraphAPI Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=puja41), but if I try to view the "friends" connection, I get `"Unsupported operation"` as a response message.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your acces token is wrong.
Try this URL with your acces token inserted on your browser
https://graph.facebook.com/puja41/friends?access_token=YOURTOKENHERE